# Javascript time conversion regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a method using regular expressions in .Net to convert time from e.g. "1h 20m" format to double. Here is it.

```
public static double? GetTaskHours(this string tmpHours) {
  Double taskHours = 0;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpHours) && !double.TryParse(tmpHours, out taskHours)) {
    var match = Regex.Match(tmpHours, @"^(?=\d)((?<hours>\d+)(h|:))?\s*((?<minutes>\d+)m?)?$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    if (match.Success) {
      int hours;
      int.TryParse(match.Groups["hours"].Value, out hours);
      int minutes;
      int.TryParse(match.Groups["minutes"].Value, out minutes);
      taskHours = (double)hours + (double)minutes / 60;
    }
  }
  return Math.Round(taskHours, 3);
}
```

Now I need the same using Javascript. I tried to convert the regex according to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_nfollow.asp but all my atempts failed. I'm very poor in regular expressions.

Here is my JS attempt.

```
function getHours(value) {
  var myArray = value.match(/^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$/g);
  var hours = myArray[2];
  var minutes = myArray[5];
  return Number(hours) + Number(minutes) / 60;
}
```

Is it correct?
Can you please show me the way?

Regards, Dmitry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String.match method will return only an array of the complete matches, not of any groups. Use the Regex.exec method to get all the groups:

```
function getHours(value) {
    var myArray = (/^((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$/g).exec(value);
    var hours = myArray[2];
    var minutes = myArray[5];
    return Number(hours) + Number(minutes) / 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't really need the `g` modifier. So you can also try this:
(just `g` removed)

```
function getHours(value) {
  var myArray = value.match(/^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$/);
  var hours = myArray[2];
  var minutes = myArray[5];
  return Number(hours) + Number(minutes) / 60;
}
getHours("3h 30m")
```