# Javascript regexp exec doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

Recently I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230526/javascript-time-conversion-regexp) about time format conversion via regular expressions in JS.

Now I modified the code a bit.

```
function getHours(value) {
  if (value == 0)
    return 0;
  var re = new RegExp("^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$", "g");
  var myArray = re.exec(value);
  var hours = 0;
  var minutes = 0;
  if (myArray != null) {
    if (myArray[2] != null) {
      hours = myArray[2];
    }
    if (myArray[5] != null) {
      minutes = myArray[5];
    }
  }
  return Number(hours) + Number(minutes) / 60;
}
```

The problem is that it returns a `null` value in `myArray`.

As I'm new to JS, I couldn't solve this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the value of `value` variable too

Comment: it can be one of `{"11h20m","11h","20","20m","11:20"}`

Comment: What should `(?=\d)` do? There is `x(?=y)` which means `matches x only if x is followed by y` but then you miss the preceding value.

Comment: @zeroflagL that means that sting must start with digit

Comment: @StNickolas you already have `\d+` (one ore more digits) as first value, so it already must start with a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
new RegExp("^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$", "g");
```

When you create a new Regular Expression through the constructor, you provide strings. In string literals, the backslash character (`\`) means ‘escape the next character’.

You have to escape those backslashes, so they won't escape their subsequent character. So the correct version is:

```
new RegExp("^(?=\\d)((\\d+)(h|:))?\\s*((\\d+)m?)?$", "g");
```

See [this article on values, variables, and literals from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) for more information on escaping characters in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in this line:

```
var re = new RegExp("^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$", "g");
```

Pls understand that `RegExp class` takes a String as argument to construct and you need to double escape `\d` and `\s` to be correctly interpreted by RegEx engine so `\d` should become `\\d` and `\s` should become `\\s`in your regex String like this:

```
var re = new RegExp("^(?=\\d)((\\d+)(h|:))?\\s*((\\d+)m?)?$", "g");
```

Note that you can also do:

```
var re = /^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed exec call like this: 
`var myArray = (/^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$/g).exec(value);`

And it worked! Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: Wrong initialization, try: `var re = new RegExp(/^(?=\d)((\d+)(h|:))?\s*((\d+)m?)?$/g)`. JavaScript string escapes "\" symbol, that is why you initialized completely different `RegExp`.